# Jquery scrollTop working half way

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am having an accordion content where i am scrolling to the top of the chosen content.
It works when I click on it the first time, but when one accordion is open the selected text does scroll much further then it should. If I first close all accordions it works fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) 
{
    $(".slider .sliderlead").click(function()
    {
        $(this).siblings(".sliderlead").removeClass("active");
        $(this).siblings(".sliderContent").removeClass("active");

        $(this).next(".sliderContent").slideToggle("slow");

        $(this).next(".sliderContent")
            .toggleClass("active")
            .siblings(".sliderContent:visible")
            .slideUp("slow");

        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $(".sliderlead.active").offset().top
        }, 150);
    });

    $(".slider .sliderContent").click(function()
    {
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
        $(this).removeClass("active");   
        $(".slider .sliderlead").removeClass("active");
    });
```

I would appreciate any tips on this one, I was spending all weekend on figuring it out, but could not find a solution.

Comment: We'll need to see some HTML + CSS for sure

Comment: Also, the entire point of the *accordion* layout is that it's impossible to have more than one section opened at a time

Comment: Hi Evan you can see the whole thing in action here http://facing-test.ncag.ch/?page_id=4221